# How do I programmatically add a fragment to a fragment in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a fragment which is really a screen in my app... on this screen I want to load one of a number of fragments depending on the properties of a model which gets passed to the screen fragment. I'll do this using a conditional when... but first:

I can't actually even load a basic fragment. Here is the code for the screen fragment:

class EditCommandFragment : Fragment() {

```
private val args by navArgs<EditCommandFragmentArgs>()
private lateinit var fragContainer: ConstraintLayout

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    setHasOptionsMenu(true)

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_edit_command, container, false)
    //get a reference to the container.
    fragContainer = view.findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.command_edit_container)
    
    // add one of the edit fragments //this doesn't work
    childFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(fragContainer, EditCommandUIFragment.newInstance()).commit()

    return view
}
```

This error thrown is:

None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied:

```
public open fun add(p0: Fragment, p1: String?): FragmentTransaction defined in androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction
public open fun add(p0: Int, p1: Fragment): FragmentTransaction defined in androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction
```

but this makes no sense. In all the tutorials I can find you pass the container as p0 and then the class of the fragment you want to add as p1... but this is asking for a string or an int, what??

How do I correctly add my EditCommandUIFragment to the container?

Comment: The "String" is a "TAG" in case you later want to do `childFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(...)`. What you want is to create an instance of the fragment you want to add (`EditCommandUIFragment`), obtain the container where you intend to put this (`fragContainer` in your example), and then call `childFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(yourFragmentContainer, instanceOfYourNewFragment, "some tag or null if you don't care")`

Comment: This doesn't work either, where in this example is it specified that the instance should be added to fragContainer?

Comment: Check the full answer, that's how it works, the container is for the FragManager to know WHERE to put the fragment, the fragment instance is because that's how the API is designed, the "tag" is optional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a Fragment you need an instance of the Fragment, not its "view" (that's the Fragment's responsibility to manage).

1. Construct an instance of your "child" Fragment by using the "recommended methods":

```
val yourNewFragment = YourNewFragment.newInstance()
```

2. Obtain the container where you will place this...

```
val container = R.id.place_where_you_will_put_it
```

3. Perform the transaction:

```
childFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(container, yourNewFragment, "A TAG or NULL")
```

Now, keep in mind, if you do use a Tag, it's sometimes good practice (this really depends on your app/lifecycle/etc.) to check if the fragment is not there already...

```
val frag = childFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("The Tag You Used Above")

if (frag == null) { 
   // add it
}
```

You get the idea.

If you do not use a TAG" then you can use the other alternative...

```
val frag = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(id of the container where the fragment is supposed to be, aka: R.id.place_where_you_will_put_it)
```

This can be used to, for example, `replace(...)` a fragment, instead of `add`.

Comment: Ah thanks, working through this now. Will vote if working. :)

Comment: This throws a: cannot access 'add': it is package-private in 'FragmentTransaction' error

Comment: Got rid of the error by not using FindViewById and actually just putting R.id.... into as p0 in add(). No errors thrown now ,but the fragment is not appearing, even though it appears to be added.

Comment: Wait, I was being a plonker. I removed .commit() for some reason along the way! All working now thanks! :)

Comment: LOL good luck :) my bad about the container, it's the `R.id.container`, not the actual view.

Answer (score 0):

I, in my project, to do something similar to yours I used viewPager2

In practice, in the parent fragment, you position it inside the xml file that acts as a view

```
 <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2 android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tabs"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        />
```

then create a class that extends from FragmentStateAdapter

```
class  ViewPagerAdapter(fragment: Fragment) : FragmentStateAdapter(fragment) {

    private val mFragmentList = ArrayList<Fragment>()
    private val mFragmentTitleList = ArrayList<String>()



    fun addFrag(fragment: Fragment, title: String) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment)
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return mFragmentList.size
    }

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        return mFragmentList[position]
    }

}
```

after inside the on-create of the fragment parent do the setup (see the documentation)
for example in my example to add the children Fragments just call

```
 viewPagerAdapter.addFrag(MyFragment(), "Title")
```

or to say which fragment to show

```
 viewpager.currentItem = 5
```